# Inner and outer orbital limit of planets in single-star systems

Tags: astrophysics, orbital-motion, planets, stellar-evolution

I am trying to find a rough cut-off of the inner and outer orbits of native planets around a single star. I know about the Roche limit and Hill Sphere, but these are not the limits I am looking for. I suspect it has to do with the formation process of the solar system and it will depend on the planetary mass (or the distribution of dust in the early stages of stellar evolution), but I am unable to find sources online.

Suspected part of the answer for inner limit:
I accidentally bumped into this 2017 brown dwarf (BD) habitability work by Emeline Bolmont ([arxiv link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.00935.pdf)). In figure 3, they show a orbital evolution of different planets around a BD). The inner limit seems to be approximately equal to the corotation radius during the early evolution stage of the BD. How does one calculate this limit?

Comment: It sounds like the reason your request differs from the Roche limit & Hill sphere is because you're asking what sizes orbits will reach over time due to the dynamical evolution of the planetary system. I suspect hard rules about that won't be known, if only because of how much [some planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_tack_hypothesis) have (likely) moved around.